# How do I iterate the values of a given key using a multimap?

Tags: c++, iterator, find, multimap

I have a multimap with repeated keys, meaning, the same key as multiple values associated with it.
How do I iterate the values returned by `multimap.find(key)`?

Comment: This http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range  is a good start.  Please look stuff up and try it before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::multimap::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) to get a pair of iterators indicating the range containing all elements matching a key. Iterate between these iterators, including the first but excluding the second, just like you would iterate over any other range using `begin()` and `end()`.